# when retrive result of a task with "reply_to" it result tuple. and says " Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?"

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, task-queue, pika

i am using celery and RabbitMq
create a simple task and send results of the task to the "result" queue
when i connect to this que to processing on the result of the task it say  " Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?" and 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'result'}

i want result of the task to process them how i get this? i know my routing is have problem and do anything i can but reach nothing.

this is what i get when running server of the result:

```
WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: {'task_id': '84913264-6294-4c8d-9eff-927d54f7d256', 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'result': 25, 'traceback': None, 'children': []} (121b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 14, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'result'} headers={}}
```

danke - gracias - thank you - mercy

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose send result specific queue in rabbitmq. Please use `reply_to` parameter. 'apply_celery.send_task' or 'task.apply_asyncron' function have 'reply_to' parameter.

This parameter give a name to queue which to return results.

Same time you have to set parameter 'backend_url' and 'result_serializer'. I think you should sure too clearly give a 'broken_url' and 'backend_url'.
Also you should sure that given a 'result_serializer'.

Look at Documentation: [backend_url](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html#rabbitmq) or [app.Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results)

If the problem still persists, you can control that [task_ignore_result](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_ignore_result)

Comment: thank you but this isnt my answer i am using reply_to to "specific" queue and then from another server i connect to this queue but my function not work. when i connect to "specific" queue  ( this queue is has answers of another worker ) this is imedietly say "" Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!? "" and say these message have "'{empty}" exchange with "specific" routing key

Comment: Can you sure that using `return` in task function. Or Can you share result queues' parameters and code which connected queue.